# raspberry pi spi communication

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spi

I am trying to communicate between a raspberry pi 3 and pic 18F series micro controller through spi. The sending and receiving of data through spi in the 18F controller is working perfectly as the data is displayed on LCD. However the spi interface on the raspberry pi is not working - the code is printing only 0 values not matter what data is sent and only 0 values are executed.

I am using the following program:

```
import spidev
import time
#import spi.max_speed_hz = 50000000

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,1)
counter = 0

while True:
    try:
        print "writing data"
        #hello spi (ASCII)
        data = [104, 101, 108, 111, 32]
        #resp = spi.xfer2(data)
        print ">>>" + str(spi.xfer2(data))

        time.sleep(1)
        counter += 1
        if counter > 4:
            break
        time.sleep(1)
    except(keyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        spi.close()
        raise
spi.close()
print "done"
```

Output:

```
writing data
>>>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
writing data
>>>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
writing data
>>>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
writing data
>>>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
writing data
>>>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
done
```

Whatever program I run I am getting only 0 values and not the data what i send. Kindly please help.

Comment: I don't know this particular implementation but do you manage the Chip Select ? Unlike I2C, SPI devices are adressed by a separate wire, not by a preamble in the data.

Comment: Your code looks correct. I would say most likely you have a wiring or some hardware issue.

Comment: The command xfer2 itself does the chip select high and tranfers the data , it keeps the CS high throughout and sends the data, whereas the command xfer does the CS high sends data and does the CS low. I think the wiring is correct but I do not know where is the problem.

Comment: A bit ancient now, but a circuit diagram and some idea of the code on the other side would help. Common issues can be level shifting, pull down/pull ups, clock and data swapped, too fast a rate, or just the other side not responding.